# Multiple Source -Multiple Destinations

Tags: algorithm, optimization, routes

I have an optimization question.

Lets say I have a set of destinations and another corresponding set of origins. I need to link each destination with one origin.A set of vehicles start from each origin towards their respective destination.The speed of every vehicle is provided.

In the network only one vehicle is allowed to pass through an intersection in one unit time,so when there are more than one vehicle at an intersection point in the network, the vehicle can either wait to cross the intersection or can take a different path.

The main objective is to minimize the overall lateness of all vehicles to reach their destinations.

Ideas on a way to tackle that?

Comment: `The main objective is to minimize the overall lateness of all vehicles to reach their destinations.` Please clarify that better, I can think of several meanings for that (average time for a vehicle, median time, time for the slowest vehicle,....) , and others can probably think of more,

Comment: The objective is to minimize the lateness of the last vehicle reaching its destination,that is the maximum time required for all vehicle to reach their respective destination should be minimum.

Answer (score 0):

This aint a complete solution but i hope will provide a descent direction:

i think you should use "[Maximum Flow Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem)"
on Flow-network like

1. Given 'n' number of vehicles
2. define S - source
3. define O1,O2,O3...,On - Origins of the vehicles. assuming Origin is the first Intersection in the way
4. define edge S-(O1,O2,O3...,On) - Capacity = 1 per each origin, equal to total number of vehicles
5. define E - Sink
6. define D1,D2,D3...,Dn - Destinations
7. define edge (D1,D2,D3...,Dn)-E - Capacity = 1 per destination
8. each intersection defined by two vertices (in) and (out) with an edge cap=1

This will help you find a good route for all trucks, but will avoid going through a "used" intersection at all...
i think incrementing the specified intersection's capacity just after flowing through should be close.

Comment: Thanks for the approach ,i will definitely implement it.